# WARN JdbcChannelMessageStore Message with id was not deleted

Tags: spring-integration

I have a queue channel backed by a JdbcChannelMessageStore. I have two instances of this application and with high concurrency I have this warning:

```
2020-03-13 19:25:38,209 task-scheduler-5  WARN JdbcChannelMessageStore:652 - Message with id '06b73eab-727a-780f-d0fa-1b0e0dd1ea20' was not deleted.
```

Is there a way to remove them?

As far as my understanding, messages are being read twice, am I correct?

I am using SI 4.3.19.RELEASE. Here is my spring flow

```
<int:channel id="channel">
        <int:queue message-store="messageStoreBean"/>
</int:channel>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="channel 
        header-name="name" >
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="2" fixed-rate="500" >
            <int:transactional />
        </int:poller>
        ...
</int:header-value-router>

<bean id="storeQueryProviderBean" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.PostgresChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />

    <bean id="messageStoreBean" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="messageStoreDataSource" />
        <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="storeQueryProviderBean" />
        <property name="region" value="region" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like PostgreSQL doesn't guarantee exclusive reading with transactions and `LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`.

Anyway that WARN is just a note that some other process has removed the message. Nothing is duplicated if other process is similar to that poller:

```
public Message<?> pollMessageFromGroup(Object groupId) {

    final String key = getKey(groupId);
    final Message<?> polledMessage = this.doPollForMessage(key);

    if (polledMessage != null) {
        if (!this.doRemoveMessageFromGroup(groupId, polledMessage)) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return polledMessage;
}
```

You see if message was not removed, we return `null` therefore nothing to poll at the moment.

You can turn off the warning level for the `org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore` to avoid that message specifying a category level as `ERROR` in your logging config.

Comment: Thank you Artem! One more question, is necesary the transactional tag in the pooler or it can be avoided?

Comment: Yes, keep it, please. There are two sql expressions within that call, so, would be better to wrap into TX. Be sure also that you use the right TX manager: JTA or DataSource

Comment: I added the TX Manager and removed the transactional tag and the warning disappeared. Is it possible that was just that? Please, if you could show me some light here I would be gratefull.

Comment: I’d expect opposite though. How do you add a tax manager? Where is that applied? Where do you transactions then?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I added the tx manager and worked fine. I tested with two instances. One with the tx-manager+transaction tag and the original one. In the first, no warnings and on the later, the warning appears. Later on, with two instances with tx-manager+transaction tag and no more warnings. Thanks for all Artem!